# Is it possibile to save shortcut for a word that I need to write at the beginning of search sentence?

Tags: google-chrome

let's say I want to google search something related to "phpstorm", and writing:

> phpstorm how to install plugin

or

> phpstorm how to change theme

Is there possibilty to save shortcut (lets say "ps") for a word "phpstorm" that I need to write at the beggining of search sentence?

Or setting that "p" display "phpstorm" on top of suggested drop-down list.

Comment: Copy "phpstorm" to your clipboard and paste it every time.

Comment: yeah, pretty bad idea.

Comment: Create a bookmarklet that lets you type in the search terms then prepends with phpstorm and does a search? IE `javascript:var qry=prompt('Search','search terms');window.location.href='https://www.google.com/search?q=phpstorm '+encodeURIComponent(qry.trim());`

Comment: Is it for Internet Explorer only? ahhh IE mneans i.e.. ok. thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From chrome settings choose "Manage search engine" and add new default search engine with prepared url:

[image]

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=phpstorm+%s
```

Then by pressing p+tab in search input write searching sentence:

[image]

And word "phpstorm" will be added at the beginning of sentence:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you install Firefox along side Chrome you could switch to Firefox to do it. It's called Firefox keyword search and works well. I have "yt" set up for a YouTube search and plain old "g" to Google search whatever comes after my keyword.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-search-from-address-bar

Comment: thanks, good to know (pity that so hard to switch from favourite browser)

Comment: There might be a Chrome extension that enables it, cos it's a feature in Firefox that's been around for some time now. Good luck!